# Multiple Counts in one Select Statement using Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This returns the count for the # of rows in `Table` & `Table2` compounded, but I would like to return just the count of `Table2` , preferrably in ONE select statement.

```
 SELECT Table.Name, Count(Table2.Active) FROM Table
 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Active = 1
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Your join does not make sense - it is not joining records in the classic sense, it's creating their unfiltered *cartesian product*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the query in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT Table.Name, (SELECT Count(Active) FROM Table2) 
FROM Table
 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Active = 1
```

I didn't change your tables "join" but it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to pull the count from the second table once for every row in the first table? This is vastly inefficient. Much better to do:

```
DECLARE @c INT;
SELECT @c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table2;
SELECT Name, @c FROM dbo.Table;
```

No, this doesn't meet your requirement of "single statement" but I'm curious why you think that is a measure for a good or efficient query.